# Ошибка после срабатывания функции в ассоциативном массиве JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

У меня записан следующий код:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.login("NjM4Njk0ODQyMzg5NDk1ODQ5.XbgdAw.yMTBoGRiFSBEn0JtneLQgmq50Bc");
command = {
"/hello": function(message) {
    message.channel.send("Hello!");
},
"/help": function(message) {
    message.channel.send({
        embed: {
            color: 1274,
            description: "Help command activated!"
        }
    });
}
};

client.on("message", (message) => {
var comm = message.content.split(" ")[0];
command[comm](message);
/*if(message.content.startsWith("/help")) {
    message.channel.send({
        embed: {
            color: 1274,
            description: "Help command activated!"
        }
    });
}*/
});
```

И выдает следующую ошибку после выполнения первой функции:

```
    TypeError: command[comm] is not a function
        at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dzyga\Desktop\test\test.js:22:18)
    [90m    at Client.emit (events.js:210:5)[39m
        at MessageCreateHandler.handle 
 (C:\Users\dzyga\Desktop\test\node_modules\[4mdiscord.js[24m\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\dzyga\Desktop\test\node_modules\[4mdiscord.js[24m\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\dzyga\Desktop\test\node_modules\[4mdiscord.js[24m\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\dzyga\Desktop\test\node_modules\[4mdiscord.js[24m\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\dzyga\Desktop\test\node_modules\[4mws[24m\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
[90m    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)[39m
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\dzyga\Desktop\test\node_modules\[4mws[24m\lib\websocket.js:789:20)
[90m    at Receiver.emit (events.js:210:5)[39m
```

Comment: Осталось узнать чему равно `comm`?

Comment: ТС, всегда проверяй входные данные от юзера. Как минимум, `if (typeof command[comm] !== 'function') { /*обработка ошибки*/ }`

Comment: спасибо ребят, я решил проблему сам. оказалось, что бот считывал выводимый самим собой текст после команды и пытался искать его в объекте